# Feed not refreshing again if I'm logged in

Tags: bug, android-app

My Stack Exchange feed fails to refresh on two Pixel 3 phones on Android 9 if I'm logged in - if I'm not logged in they refresh fine (see screenshots).

This seems similar to the issue people reported back in 2016, but of the issue not closed as duplicate, the resolution was to upgrade Android / wait until the feed is regenerated; it's been a day since I first noticed the issue and it's still happening

[image: feed refresh error]
[image: feed working anonymous 1]
[image: feed working anonymous 2]

- App Version: 1.0.95
- Device Manufacturer: Google
- Device Model: Pixel 3

  - OS Version: 9 (5108886)

Comment: I'm getting this issue now. same version. Sony Xperia XZ F8331. Android Version 8.0.0, build number 41.3.A.2.192